# Decrease size of container of non-default-constructible elements using unary resize

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, default-constructor

Using `push_back`/`emplace_back` (rare `push_front`/`emplace_front` or even `push_after`/`emplace_after`) I can fill almost any container from the STL. Even container of non-default-constructible elements. Size decreasing requires only a presence of elements' destructors (moreover, containers necessarily require, that the elements to be [Destructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Destructible)). But I can't simply use `resize` (if present) to reduce size of containers of non-default-constructible elements. Instead I have to use a workaround even for a least exacting (to special functions) of them: `std::list`.

```
#include <list>

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    // construct
    std::list< std::reference_wrapper< int > > l;
    // fill
    int i{};
    l.emplace_back(i);
    int j{};
    l.emplace_back(j);
    // save intermediate state for future
    std::size_t const size = l.size();
    // continue appending
    int k{};
    l.emplace_back(k);
    // now I want to rollback to saved state
    //l.resize(size); // just need to call the destructors, but illegal due to not default constructible value_type
    // so I have to use a workaround
    for (std::size_t s = l.size(); size < s; --s) {
        l.pop_back();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even for unary [`std::list::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/resize) version `std::list::value_type` should be [DefaultInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultInsertable).

I want unary `resize(std::size_t)` be intended for "decrease size" purpose only in described above kind of containers. It is possible to prohibit `resize(std::size_t, value_type = value_type())` participation in overloading resolution (say, using base class dispatching) in favor of `resize(std::size_t)`/`resize(std::size_t, value_type)` pair if `value_type` is not [DefaultConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible). If desired size is greater then current size such `resize(std::size_t)` should throw, say, `std::bad_alloc`. Is it possible design?

Comment: If you're trying to decrease the size, could you use something like erase or splice to pull out the elements you don't want?

Comment: @templatetypedef On the one hand `erase` (even `std::deque::erase`) can lead to excessive invalidation of references and iterators of non-erased elements, on the other hand `erase` requires a iterator/iterators pair - it more verbose, then just `resize(123);`.

Comment: Though, for `std::list`, no iterators outside the range will be invalidated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value_type` has to be default constructible (DefaultInsertable) because the interface to `resize` contains code to both increase and decrease the size. Even if you just use half the code, the entire function has to compile.

There is also a two-parameter `resize` where you supply the value to use when the size is increased. In that case, the `value_type` doesn't have to be default constructible.

So, if you call `l.resize(size, dummy_value)` you have lifted the restriction on the type. Here `dummy_value` might be `l.front()`, or any other element you have handy. If the `size` parameter is less than `l.size()`, it will not be used anyway.

Comment: It is good workaround, unless `vlaue_type` is heavy copy-/move-constructible. What if the number of values is finite and restricted? For non-copy-/move-constructible type I still can fill the container using `emplace` functions I can't use it and problem remains valid.

Comment: No, the second parameter to `resize` is not moved or copied, unless the resize operation makes the container larger. Otherwise, it is just passed by const reference to the function and not used.

Comment: Second parameter declared as `value_type = value_type()`. It is not a reference - is a value. (Hmmm, until C++11 though).

Comment: Ok, then you have an old implementation. In C++11 there are [two different resize functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). In C++98 all types stored in containers **had** to be default constructible.

Comment: You are right. I use modern implementation, but read the original sources.

Comment: Finally I use your approach in form `if (old_size < l.size()) l.resize(old_size, l.back());`. Inter alia it includes `assert(l.empty());` protection for `l.back();` due to `std::size_t` is unsigned and its least value is `0`.

Comment: The two-parameter form unconditionally requires CopyInsertable.